# adding Azure reports to MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-sql-reporting

I want to embed reports to a MVC application which are hosted on Azure Reporting Server.

Do any one have any idea ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

You'll be aware that the regular ReportViewer is not MVC-friendly (if ever there was an understatement...)

My approach has been to use the Report Execution service (https:///reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx) directly.

Basic steps are:

1. Logon to the report server with the .LogonUser method
2. Load the report with the .LoadReport method
3. Set the .ExecutionHeader property to a new ExecutionHeader object
4. Build any parameters and set them using the .SetExecutionParameters method
5. Render the report using the .Render method
6. Get the HTML content of the report using the appropriate encoding (which you'll get from the .Render method)

I've encapsulated this lot in a controller action that returns a Content ActionResult containing the report.

You'll have to forego most of the rich interactive features, as they don't tend to play nicely (or you can put the work into sorting out why).

However, I'm now moving away from SQL Azure Reporting Services. For my application, I found it was just too slow and limited. SQL Azure will terminate a query that takes more than a minute and in my case (primarily because of the complexity of the underlying queries) many of my reports consistently time out.

Your mileage, of course, may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give active reports a try,active reports supports hosting reports on a Azure.You can find more details about creating a MVC application using Active Reports here

http://www.gcpowertools.info/2011/11/using-active-reports-in-mvc-3.html

You can find more about Active Reports [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Products/ActiveReports/Overview.aspx) and about Azure support [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/arWindowsAzureSupport.html)